# How to create a zoomable grid for game in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to create simple 2d, grid-based game (like tic-tac-toe, but with a lot of cells) in React Native. Is it possible? And how to create basic grid with zoom option?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/react-native-grid-expand/2749 it is a link to a post and discusion maybe it can help you with the zooming

Comment: Looks like doesn't work for me. I do not need fill the full screen, just zoom.  Is there any other solution?